# Javascript, Jquery - I am getting two values on index when element is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<div class="promo_tumbs col_12">
    <div data-dir="prev" class="prev"></div>
    <div data-dir="next" class="next"></div>
    <div class="promo_tumbs_centar">
        <a href="#first"><div class="promo_tumb promo_tumb_current">Test</div></a>
        <a href="#second"><div class="promo_tumb">Test</div></a>
        <a href="#thrid"><div class="promo_tumb">Test</div></a>
        <a href="#fourh"><div class="promo_tumb">Test</div></a>
        <a href="#fifth"><div class="promo_tumb">Test</div></a>
        <a href="#fifth"><div class="promo_tumb">Test</div></a>
        <a href="#fifth"><div class="promo_tumb">Test</div></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function Slider(container, nav) {
    this.container = container;
    this.nav = nav;

    this.li = this.container.find('li');
    this.li_width = this.li.first().width();
    this.li_len = this.li.length;

    this.thumbs = this.nav.find('a');

    this.current = 0;
}

Slider.prototype.transition = function(coords) {
    this.container.stop().animate({
        'margin-left': coords || -(this.current * this.li_width)
    })
}

Slider.prototype.set_current = function(dir) {
    var pos = this.current;
    if (dir === 'next') {
        pos++
    }
    else if (dir === 'prev') {
        pos--
    }
    this.current = (pos < 0) ? this.li_len - 1 : pos % this.li_len;

    return pos;
}

var slider = new Slider($('div.promo_inner ul'), $('div.promo_tumbs'));
slider.nav.find('div').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).attr("data-dir") === undefined) {
        var index = slider.thumbs.index($(this).parent('a'));

        console.log(index)
    } else {
        slider.set_current($(this).data('dir'));
    }
    slider.transition();
})​
​
```

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/6R9Wg/)

When I click on element I am getting two values - index of clicked element and -1. What is going on here? How can I loose -1 and get only index value?

Comment: In future, please don't *just* include a link to jsFiddle. Your post should standalone from any other resource; consider what'd happen if jsFiddle went down in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call event.stopPropagation(); in order to stop the propagation of event [Demo on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SvHMa/1/)

This will give you more idea what elements causing double event [Reason for multiple events JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SvHMa/3/)

Comment: If I can ask one more question - How can I remove class (promo_tumb_current) from current element and add class to the clicked element?

Comment: Do you want to change (remove then add) class of currently clicked element?

Comment: Fist it need to remove class **promo_tumb_current** and then it needs to apply that class to the clicked element and so set it to current. I managed to remove class adding this code: `slider.thumbs.children('div').removeClass('promo_tumb_current');`, but when I use `slider.thumbs.children('div').addClass('promo_tumb_current');` it adds class to all div elements. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/SvHMa/4/)

Comment: Try adding class using this statement in the click event $(this).addClass('promo_tumb_current');

Answer (score 1):

`nav.find()` also matches `<div class="promo_tumbs_centar">`. Try `find(".promo_tumb")`

Answer (score 0):

When clicking on a .promo_tumb div, you're also clicking on .promo_tumbs_centar.

You should use this :

```
slider.nav.find('.promo_tumb')
```

instead of

```
slider.nav.find('div')
```